# React native android View not showing after refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When I refresh my android emulator View disappears, after i change something in my component and save it shows up again. Does any body knows why it is happening.

Here is my code :

```
<View style={style.stopWatch}>
  <Text style={style.text}>
   Some text
  </Text>
</View>

   style = StyleSheet.create({
    stopWatch: {
     borderRadius: 100,
     width: 100,
     height: 100,
     backgroundColor: 'black',
     alignItems: 'center',
     justifyContent: 'center'
    },     
    text: {
     color: 'white',
     justifyContent: 'center',
    },
```

Comment: could you post your example to rnplay.org?